# Current Location GPS, Program closes unexpectidly

Tags: android, geolocation, gps

I am trying to get current location through GPS. But my application closes unexpectidly. I cannot get the reason. I have aaded the permission in AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
```

the code I am trying is as follows:

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
    return true;
}

public void getLoc()
{
    LocationManager manager = (LocationManager)getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);          
    LocationListener listener = new MyLocationListener();
    manager.requestLocationUpdates( LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 5000, 10, listener);
}

public class MyLocationListener implements LocationListener    {
@Override

public void onLocationChanged(Location loc) 
{
    loc.getLatitude();
    loc.getLongitude();
    String Text = "My current location is: " + "Latitude = " + loc.getLatitude() + "Longitude = " + loc.getLongitude();
    Toast.makeText( getApplicationContext(), Text, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}

@Override

public void onProviderDisabled(String provider)
{
    Toast.makeText( getApplicationContext(), "Gps Disabled", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT ).show();
}

@Override

public void onProviderEnabled(String provider)
{
    Toast.makeText( getApplicationContext(), "Gps Enabled", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}

@Override

public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras)
{        }
}
```

}

Comment: What Logcat messages do you get when your App stops? Mosten times there will be some kind of stack trace that tells you where something goes wrong. Please find that part of information in your Eclipse-Logcat view and post it here.

Comment: What error do you see in LogCat?

Comment: Btw. you can simply use `this` when in need for a `Context` in an `Activity` (like in your `Toast.makeText(...)` calls. No need for `getApplicationContext()`.

Comment: where is your `getLoc()` called from? don't see any reference in the existing code

Comment: getLoc() is called on button click event

Comment: I am not running it on virtual device. don't know the procedure to run it on AVD. Running it on the actual device..

Answer (score 1):

Try this.
first of all make this code simple.

add this line inside onCreate coz i m not seeing any getloc method called in onCreate

```
LocationManager manager = (LocationManager)getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);          
    LocationListener listener = new MyLocationListener();
    manager.requestLocationUpdates( LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 5000, 10, listener);
```

and for testing change these values to 0

```
manager.requestLocationUpdates( LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, listener);
```

and change onLocationChange with this method.

```
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
    int lat = (int) (location.getLatitude());
    int lng = (int) (location.getLongitude());
    latituteField.setText(String.valueOf(lat));
    longitudeField.setText(String.valueOf(lng));
  }
```

or try this [link](http://www.hrupin.com/2011/04/android-gps-using-how-to-get-current-location-example)

Answer (score 1):

Try this,It might help you

```
LocationManager mlocManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
   LocationListener mlocListener = new MyLocationListener();

 mlocManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0,
        mlocListener);



public class MyLocationListener implements LocationListener {

@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location loc) {
    loc.getLatitude();
    loc.getLongitude();

    Geocoder gcd = new Geocoder(getApplicationContext(),
            Locale.getDefault());
    try {
        mAddresses = gcd.getFromLocation(loc.getLatitude(),
                loc.getLongitude(), 1);

    } catch (IOException e) {

    }

    String cityName = (mAddresses != null) ? mAddresses.get(0)
            .getLocality() : TimeZone.getDefault().getID();
    String countryName = (mAddresses != null) ? mAddresses.get(0)
            .getCountryName() : Locale.getDefault().getDisplayCountry()
            .toString();


    mCurrentSpeed.setText(loc.getSpeed());
}

@Override
public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Gps Disabled",
            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}

@Override
public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Gps Enabled",
            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}

@Override
public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
}
}
```